# How to invoke watir scripts from a web application?

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver, browser-automation

I have a watir script ,that i have to run from a web interface, on the same browser invoking the scripts. Is it possible?

Comment: This is a strange requirement: watir is a testing tool. Why do you have this requirement?

Comment: we need an interface that runs the scripts & generates performance reports using httpwatch etc

Comment: @adthi Why does performance report generation depend on you running watir scripts from a web interface? At the end of the day you're only running a ruby script. Colour me confused.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible to do, as a browser doesn't understand what ruby is.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it is possible.  I've been intending to begin a similar project to what adithi wanted to do at some point, using PHP.  From PHP, you can use the shell_exec command or backtick operator to execute commands in the shell.  The ruby returns output using puts, which can be read by the PHP.

http://chipmunkninja.com/Program-Execution-in-PHP%3A-exec-m@ seems to be a good page detailing this technique.